# How do Python enums enforce read access only?

Tags: python, enums

I understand that in Python constants are implied, but not enforced, by an uppercase variable name. I also understand that by subclassing from Enum, a class can implement an enumerated type which prevents the individual enumerated values from being overwritten.

These two idioms seem to me to be somewhat at odds with each other and I was wondering how the Enum solution enforced read-only access to the variable values.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/db6f297d448ce46e58a5b90239a4779553333198/Lib/enum.py#L837-L848

Comment: Jon's comment explains the how – and the inevitable "Well, how do I sidestep that"?: `object.__setattr__(MyEnumClass, "foo", "bar")`, i.e. use a superclass's non-overridden `__setattr__`.

Comment: @AKX: your code snippet has added an ordinary attribute, not an enum member -- `foo` will not show up in `list()`, etc., and can be overridden normally (i.e. `MyEnumClass.foo = 9` works).

Comment: @EthanFurman I never claimed it would add an enum member, either :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two Python features that make this possible:

1. Magic methods
2. Metaclasses

I will use type annotations throughout this answer to hopefully make the code clearer, but keep in mind that they are not necessary and have no effect at runtime.

### Magic methods

The Python language provides several "hooks" that can customize how objects behave.

For example, if an object has a `__str__` method, the builtin function `str()` calls that method to obtain a result. Such methods are called "magic methods" or "dunders" (short for "double underscores") by the Python community, and are documented at various points in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html.

It might be surprising to learn that Python provides a [`__setattr__` hook method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) that is called whenever an attribute is set on an object. Example:

```py
from typing import Any

class Talkative:
    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        print(f"Setting attribute {name!r} on {self!r}: {value!r}")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

obj = Talkative()
obj.a = "xyz"
obj.b = -1
```

Output:

```
Setting attribute 'a' on <__main__.Talkative object at 0x104ea3250>: 'xyz'
Setting attribute 'b' on <__main__.Talkative object at 0x104ea3250>: -1
```

However, this `__setattr__` customization applies to *instances* of the `Talkative` class, but not the `Talkative` class object itself. For example, the following produces no output because the `__setattr__` method is not called:

```py
Talkative.idea = "lightbulb"
```

Python classes are themselves just regular Python objects of class `type`:

```py
assert isinstance(Talkative, type)
```

Being objects, classes themselves can have methods, attributes, etc. Importantly, this includes magic methods like `__setattr__`. So the `Talkative` class itself is just an object, and it can have its own `__setattr__` method.

Our usual mechanism for defining methods won't work here. We need a mechanism to define custom methods on class objects themselves, rather than on instances of classes. For that, we use metaclasses.

### Metaclasses

A "metaclass" is the class of a class. (Much has been written about them elsewhere, so I won't go into great detail here.)

Normally, classes are instances of `type`, but we can define our own custom *subclass* of `type` that implements whatever custom behavior we desire. In this case, we want a `__setattr__` method in a metaclass, to customize setting attributes on a class object itself.

```py
class TalkativeType(type):
    def __setattr__(cls, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        print(f"Setting attribute {name!r} on {cls!r}: {value!r}")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

class Talkative(metaclass=TalkativeType):
    pass

Talkative.q = "bert"
```

Output:

```
Setting attribute 'q' on <class '__main__.Talkative'>: 'bert'
```

Note that we use the parameter name `cls` instead of `self`, to indicate that we are operating on classes, not instances of classes. The name of this parameter is irrelevant to Python, so we can use whatever we like.

##### Side note for advanced readers

Why we can't manually bind our custom function to the `Talkative` class?

For example, you might try this:

```py
from types import MethodType

class Talkative2:
    pass

def talkative_setattr(self, name, value):
    print(f"Setting attribute {name!r} on {self!r}: {value!r}")
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

Talkative2.__setattr__ = MethodType(talkative_setattr, Talkative2)
Thing.q = "bert"
```

The reason is that dunders are *not* looked up using the normal attribute mechanisms. They are looked up directly on the class of the object being operated on, not on the object instance itself. Therefore the type of `Talkative2` itself must provide a special `__setattr__` function, and the  `Talkative2.__setattr__` attribute is simply ignored. In this case, the class of `Talkative2` is simply `type`, which does *not* have a `__setattr__` method, even though `Talkative2` does have a `__setattr__` method, so the default behavior results.

*Many thanks to these members of the Python Discord server for helping me understand the details of this section: `L3viathan`, `godlygeek`, and `lakmatiol`.*

### Putting it together

If we look at the Python source code, we can see exactly these two techniques in use: a metaclass `EnumType`, of which `Enum` is an instance, that implements a `__setattr__` method:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2305ca51448552542b2414186252123a8dc87db7/Lib/enum.py#L837-L848

```py
class EnumType(type):
    """
    Metaclass for Enum
    """

    ...

    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        """
        Block attempts to reassign Enum members.

        A simple assignment to the class namespace only changes one of the
        several possible ways to get an Enum member from the Enum class,
        resulting in an inconsistent Enumeration.
        """
        member_map = cls.__dict__.get('_member_map_', {})
        if name in member_map:
            raise AttributeError('cannot reassign member %r' % (name, ))
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

...

class Enum(metaclass=EnumType):
```

*Credit goes to `jonrsharpe` for having the good sense to link to the source code.*